# how to run two branches at the same time in Jenkins

Tags: branch, jenkins-pipeline

Everyone.

I have got a very basic question that I didn't find out yet :

How to run two branches at the same time in Jenkins?

I actually have two branches in my multi-branch pipeline Jenkinsfile.

[image: Build image]

However, I need to run one branch for development and the other for production.

Is there any way to build them?

If not, please advise me on a good way.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate your use-case? the multibranch pipeline will by default execute pipeline for multiple branches based on the trigger.  If you enable webhook, both dev and pro will execute if there is a something has been pushed on those branches.